# Internet Problems Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: internet-connection

I have just installed ubuntu onto my laptop and i am having some difficulties with the internet.
It tells me that it has connected to the network yet when i try to run firefox or try to update it is unable to do anything.
I have tried using wireless and wired but im getting the same results from each.
Some help with this issue would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the new Ubuntu. Try `initctl start network-manager`

Still haven't found a solution to this yet but that gets it running